# Algorithm to split set of objects into certain number of groups?

Tags: algorithm, split, grouping

For example, say I have a 2D array of pixels (in other words, an image) and I want to arrange them into groups so that the number of groups will add up perfectly to a certain number (say, the total items in another 2D array of pixels). At the moment, what I try is using a combination of ratios and pixels, but this fails on anything other than perfect integer ratios (so 1:2, 1:3, 1:4, etc). When it does fail, it just scales it to the integer less than it, so, for example, a 1:2.93 ratio scale would be using a 1:2 scale with part of the image cut off. I'd rather not do this, so what are some algorithms I could use that do not get into Matrix Multipication? I remember seeing something similar to what I described at first mentioned, but I cannot find it. Is this an NP-type problem?

For example, say I have a 12-by-12 pixel image and I want to split it up into exactly 64 sub-images of n-by-m size. Through analysis one could see that I could break it up into 8 2-by-2 sub-images, and 56 2-by-1 sub-images in order to get that exact number of sub-images. So, in other words, I would get 8+56=64 sub-images using all 4(8)+56(2)=144 pixels.

Similarly, if I had a 13 by 13 pixel image and I wanted to 81 sub-images of n-by-m size, I would need to break it up into 4 2-by-2 sub-images, 76 2-by-1 sub-images, and 1 1-by-1 sub-image to get the exact number of sub-images needed. In other words, 4(4)+76(2)+1=169 and 4+76+1=81.

Yet another example, if I wanted to split the same 13 by 13 image into 36 sub-images of n-by-m size, I would need 14 4-by-2 sub-images, 7 2-by-2 sub-images, 14 2-by-1 sub-images, and 1 1-by-1 sub-image. In other words,  8(13)+4(10)+2(12)+1=169 and 13+10+12+1=36.

Of course, the image need not be square, and neither the amount of sub-images, but neither should not be prime. In addition, the amount of sub-images should be less than the number of pixels in the image. I'd probably want to stick to powers of two for the width and height of the sub-images for ease of translating one larger sub image into multiple sub images, but if I can find an algorithm which didn't do that it'd be better. That is basically what I'm trying to find an algorithm for.

Comment: I don't know if I understand your question. Let's say you have a 10x10 pixels image, and you want to divide it into 9 sub-images. Since pixels are discrete entities, the only solution that I see is that you generate 9 sub-images of size 3x3, which obviously cut part of the original image out.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do, actually. Of course, that would make things slightly harder, but I'd probably have a lot more groups of 1 pixel than any others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to split a rectabgular image of a given size, into `n` rectangular sub-images. Let say that you have:

- an image of size `w * h`
- and you want to split into `n` sub-images of size `x * y`

I think that what you want is

```
R = { (x, y) | x in [1..w], y in [1..h], x * y == (w * h) / n }
```

That is the set of pairs `(x, y)` such that `x * y` is equal to `(w * h) / n`, where `/` is the integer division. Also, you probably want to take the `x * y` rectangle having the smallest perimeter, i.e. the smallest value of `x + y`.

For the three examples in the questions:

- splitting a `12 x 12` image into 64 sub-images, you get `R = {(1,2),(2,1)}`, and so you have either 64 `1 x 2` sub-images, or 64 `2 x 1` sub-images
- splitting a `13 x 13` image into 81 sub-images, you het `R = {(1,2),(2,1)}`, and so you have either 64 `1 x 2` sub-images, or 64 `2 x 1` sub-images
- splitting a `13 x 13` image into 36 sub-images, you het `R = {(1,4),(2,2),(4,1)}`, and so you could use 36 `2 x 2` sub-images (smallest perimeter)

For every example, you can of course combine different size of rectangles.

If you want to do something else, maybe *tiling* your original image, you may want to have a look at [rectangle tiling algorithms](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/149445/Rectangle-Tiling-Algorithm.aspx)

Comment: Wouldn't that create all the sub-images of the same size? If so, that is not what I want since I know that for some groups will have to be different sizes in order to total up to the certain amount of groups I needed.

Comment: @Smartboy: yes, my solution gives sub-images having the same size `(x, y)`. I'm afraid I don't understand your additional constraint about groups having different sizes. Could you perhaps edit your question, and clarify it with an example?

Comment: @MarcoS I edited it and hopefully clarified what I am trying to do with a couple examples. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the subimages being differently sized, a simple way to do this is repeatedly splitting subimages in two. Every new split increases the number of subimages by one.