# Splitting a given rectangle into n subrectangles

Tags: list, haskell

## Preliminary remarks

I am learning Haskell.

A [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5828452/algorithm-to-split-set-of-objects-into-certain-number-of-groups) that I answered some days ago gave me the inspiration for this exercise in Haskell, which gave the opportunity for experimenting with the few things that I've learned up to now, and also left me with questions :)

## Problem statement

Given a rectangle **A** of width `w` and height `h` find the best rectangle **B** that fits `n` times within **A**, where *best* means having the smallest perimeter.

## My attempt

I've started with the basic idea of generating the set of sub-rectangles of **A** having an area equal to `div (w * h) n`, and then picking the one having the smallest perimeter.

Here are the three implementations of this idea that I came up with; they're in chronological order: I got the inspiration for the third after having done the second, which I got after having done the first (OK, there's a version 0, in which I didn't use `data Rectangle` but just a tuple `(x, y)`):

### Implementation 1

```
data Rectangle = Rectangle { width :: Integer,
                             height :: Integer
                           } deriving (Show)

subRectangles :: Rectangle -> Integer -> [ Rectangle ]
subRectangles r n = [ Rectangle x y | x <- [1..w ], y <- [1..h], x * y == (w * h) `div` n ]
                  where w = width r
                        h = height r

bestSubRectangle :: [ Rectangle ] -> Rectangle
bestSubRectangle [ r ] = r
bestSubRectangle (r:rs)
  | perimeter r < perimeter bestOfRest = r
  | otherwise = bestOfRest
  where bestOfRest = bestSubRectangle rs

perimeter :: Rectangle -> Integer
perimeter r = (width r) + (height r)
```

### Implementation 2

```
data Rectangle = Rectangle { width :: Integer,
                             height :: Integer
                           } deriving (Show)

subRectangles :: Rectangle -> Integer -> [ Rectangle ]
subRectangles r n = [ Rectangle x y | x <- [1..w ], y <- [1..h], x * y == (w * h) `div` n ]
                  where w = width r
                        h = height r

bestSubRectangle :: [ Rectangle ] -> Rectangle
bestSubRectangle xs = foldr smaller (last xs) xs

smaller :: Rectangle -> Rectangle -> Rectangle
smaller r1 r2 
  | perimeter r1 < perimeter r2 = r1
  | otherwise = r2

perimeter :: Rectangle -> Integer
perimeter r = (width r) + (height r)
```

### Implementation 3

```
import Data.List

data Rectangle = Rectangle { width :: Integer,
                             height :: Integer
                           } deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Ord Rectangle where
  (Rectangle w1 h1) `compare` (Rectangle w2 h2) = (w1 + h1) `compare` (w2 + h2)

subRectangles :: Rectangle -> Integer -> [ Rectangle ]
subRectangles r n = [ Rectangle x y | x <- [1..w ], y <- [1..h], x * y == (w * h) `div` n ]
                  where w = width r
                        h = height r

bestSubRectangle :: [ Rectangle ] -> Rectangle
bestSubRectangle = head . sort
```

## Questions

1. Which approach is more idiomatic?
2. Which approach is better in terms of performance? `bestSubRectangle` in Implementation 3 depends on `sort`, which is at best O(n lg n), while in Implementation 1, 2 `bestSubRectangle` requires only scanning the array returned by `subRectangles`, thus making it O(n). However I'm not sure if/how Haskell laziness works on `bestSubRectangle = head . sort`: will `sort` produce only the first element of the sorted array, because of `head` requiring only the first element (`head (x:_) =  x)`?
3. In implementation 3, when making `Rectangle` an instance of `Ord` should I also define the other methods of the `Ord` class? Is this the right way to make `Rectangle` an instance of `Ord`?

Any further suggestion/recommendation to improve is highly welcome.

Comment: Do the widths and heights have to be integers?  The problem statement doesn't specify.

Comment: @pat: yes, widths and heights are `Integer`. Actually they should be _positive_ integers, but I don't know how to add this additional constraint

Comment: @MarcoS, what do you means with fits n times in **A**? Exactly fit? I would just make **B** of dimensions 0x0, then the perimeter is 0 and it clearly fits in **A**.

Comment: Your implementations are not correct, if I read the problem statement correctly: `bestSubRectangle $ subRectangles (Rectangle 4 3) 3` comes up in all three with `Rectangle {width = 2, height = 2}`, but you can't fit 3 2x2 squares in a 4x3 rectangle. That said, `head . sort` will run in `O(n)` due to laziness, and you could also try `minimumBy (comparing perimeter)` (after importing `Data.Ord`) to get around the non-standard `Ord` instance.

Comment: Do you allow some of the copies of **B** to be rotated in order to fit into **A**?

Comment: @Tarrasch: perhaps "fits `n` times in **A**" was not a good expression, sorry. I meant that you can tile **A**'s surface with `n` copies of **B**, where `n` is a positive integer. Since we're dealing with integers (`w`, `h`, and `n` are all positive integers), there are obvious cases in which you will not be able cover the entire surface of **A**: in those cases, I'm happy with the solution that leaves the smallest part of **A**'s surface uncovered. I hope this clarifies. Also, I'm not interested in the `0 x 0` solution.

Comment: @yatima2975: about you're example: you're right, however I'm happy with the solution the covers the biggest part of **A**'s surface. See above comment @Tarrasch. Thank you for suggesting `minimumBy` I will try it.

Comment: @hammar: in the original idea I did not consider rotation: all copies of **B** have the same orientation. Nevertheless rotation will make the problem more difficult and interesting, so, if you like, feel free to propose a solution for the rotation case.

Comment: BTW, you can add backticks around `div` to use it like an infix operator. (Actually this works with every function; you can even give functions there own precedence when used infix): `a \`div\` b` instead of `div a b`. Which one looks nicer?

Comment: @FUZxxl: yes, I know about the backticks: I just don't know how to escape them when using stackoverflow markdown ... but now I've found the [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/55437/how-can-the-backtick-character-be-included-in-code)

Comment: Use a backslash: `\`foo \\`bar\\` baz\`` gives `foo \`bar\` baz`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer your questions about Haskell (and not about the algorithm you've choosen):

1. I'd say your second implementation is most idiomatic.
2. You are right that the problem needs only a linear scan, so that `sort` is likely to be more expensive than needed. You are also asking the right question when asking if, due to laziness, `head . sort` will compute only the first element of the result of the `sort`. It will, but depending on how `sort` is implemented, that may very well rely on sorting the whole list before it can return the first element. You should assume that it does.
3. You can tell from the [documentation for `Ord`](http://lambda.haskell.org/hp-tmp/docs/2011.2.0.0/ghc-doc/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/Data-Ord.html#t%3aOrd) that `compare` is sufficient. The key phrase is *Minimal complete definition: either `compare` or `<=`.* Many type classes have similar use patterns. You should feel free to write a minimal implementation where they do.

Some other observations about your code (again, not the algorithm):

- Function calls bind tighter than operators, as in most languages - just in Haskell there are no parenthesis around the arguments. Hence you would write `perimeter r = width r + height r`
- If you are folding over a list that must have at least one element, you can use `foldr1` as in `bestSubRectangle xs = foldr1 smaller xs`
- Your instance of `Ord` for `Rectangle` doesn't agree with the derived instance of `Eq`. That is, there are values which will `compare` as `EQ` but would return `False` for `==`. In this case, I wouldn't try to bend `Rectangle`'s general purpose instance of `Ord` for purposes of perimeter comparison, and instead go with the `smaller` predicate you wrote in the second implementation.

Comment: thank you for answering my questions, and for the helpful observations. What if you had to comment about the algorithm too?

Comment: It is difficult to comment on the algorithm because I'm guessing problem statement isn't really what you want. For example, as stated, 1×1 rectangle will be "best", and fix n times, so long a w×h ≥ n. On the other hand, if what you are looking for is n rectangles to cover as much of w×h as possible, then, these can be searched for by starting with sqrt(w×h/n), downward (as one side). None the less, searching 1..w by 1..h is almost certainly much more expensive than needed. Finally, do these n rectangles need to tile without overlap? That raises more difficult issues....

Comment: thank you for your additional comments. I appreciate the suggestion of starting with `sqrt(w * h / n)` and go downward: that's a good idea. And yes, the `n` rectangles were meant to tile and not to overlap

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are calculating too much, inductively going through posibilities of n (number of rectangles we wish to fill up our given rectangle) we should get:

- n = 1 => always returns the given rectangle
- n = 2 => always returns the 2 rectangles given by bisecting the given rectangle on the longest side, i.e. gives the 2 most square rectangles
- n = 3 => same as 2 using 3, divide equally along longest side.
- n = 4 More complicated, essentially the question comes up is it better to put the same rectangle 4 times in a row OR is is better to bisect both length and width into a 2x2 group of rectangle. For larger numbers of n it is also a question of these configuration of factors > 1

--Essentially this is a question of factoring n, dividing the length and width by the each of the factors THEN choosing the configuration where the divided length & width (i.e. the length and width of the resulting filler rectangles) are MOST SIMILAR, (most square-like). Also note it is not necessary to try all factors against all sides. The most square rectangle will be taking the larger factor against the longer side.

- n = number of filler rectangles
- l = longest of width or height of container rectangle
- s = shortest of width or height container rectangle
- h1 = height of candidate rectangle 1
- w1 = width of candidate rectangle 1
- d = difference of candidate dimensions
- t = smallest difference in candidate height and width (initialize t to l)
- b = best fit

Therefore the steps become:

```
    1: Factor n
    2: for each factor pair of n:
       (l/largest factor) - (s/smaller factor) = d
       if d < t:
          t = d
          store current best candidate rectangle 
    3: Return best fit remaining after all factors have been tried
```